# manipulate svg outside the DOM, before ignite it

Tags: arrays, svg, browser, svg.js

So i'm working on a svg manipulation, and i'm looking at svg.js.
My question is: can i manipulate the svg in background, before import it into the DOM?
I don't need the initial image, just a manipulation i do from it.

Bests

Comment: Please elaborate: where does the "initial image" come from? Describe what workflow you want to achieve.

Comment: So basically let's say i have a svg, coming from illustrator. I can upload it in the page, but what i want to do is not to display it directly, as it is. Iwant instead select, path by path, all the element, and transform them in in something different. This new file is what i want eventually to display.

Comment: Describe "upload". To a server?

Comment: To a webpage, actually. Like at pageload time, or from the user.

Comment: Please also describe what exactly you mean by manipulation? examples of methods or whatever you want from the svg plz

Comment: You have to somewhat insert it into the dom before manipulating it. Ofc you can hide it but then methods like bbox wont work anymore. Transformations should be ok though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

svg.js is able to manipulate nodes only. Whether these are in the DOM or not does not matter in most cases. However, you cannot get a bounding box for an element which is not in the dom. This can be an issue when you use methods which rely on the `bbox` method.

Beside that its easy as:

```
let canvas = SVG.adopt(rootNode)
canvas.rect(200, 200)

// or more abstract
// creates rect node outside of the dom
let rect = new SVG.Rect().size(200, 200)
```